# Sequelize Where statement with date

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize as my backend ORM. Now I wish to do some `WHERE` operations on a Date.

More specifically, I want to get all data where a date is between now and 7 days ago.

The problem is that the documentation does not specify which operations you can do on `Datatypes.DATE`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So have you tried  $lt: (new Date ()) and $gt : (...)   replace ... with time now - 7 days

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Just like Molda says, you can use `$gt`, `$lt`, `$gte` or `$lte` with a date:

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_datetime: {
      $gte: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})
```

If you're using v5 of Sequelize, you've to include `Op` because the key was moved into `Symbol`

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_datetime: {
      [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})
```

See more [sequelize documentation here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html)

Comment: do note that this will not work from Sequelize 5... you can check out the breaking changes from Sequelize due to string based operators being insecure .. you should instead use [Op.gte] as per other comment

Comment: Or `db.Sequelize.Op` if you just import db

Comment: HI, instead using moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate(), i need  to use column name createdDate . is that possible?

Answer (score 74):

I had to import the Operators symbols from sequelize and use like so.

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_datetime: {
      [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})
```

According to the docs, for security reasons this is considered best practise.

See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html for more info.

> Using Sequelize without any aliases improves security. Some frameworks
>   automatically parse user input into js objects and if you fail to
>   sanitize your input it might be possible to inject an Object with
>   string operators to Sequelize.
>
> (...)
>
> For better security it is highly advised to use Sequelize.Op and not
>   depend on any string alias at all. You can limit alias your
>   application will need by setting operatorsAliases option, remember to
>   sanitize user input especially when you are directly passing them to
>   Sequelize methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! To further improve the quality of your answer, keep in mind that links to other websites can become unavailable, and thus it is strongly advised that you copy the relevant info from the external documentation as a citation in the body of your answer.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is the new standard for Sequelize.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use `Sequelize.literal()` to perform dates manipulation in SQL.

The following code works with Postgres, but I'm quite sure something similar could be done in other systems as well:

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_datetime: {
      $gte: Sequelize.literal('NOW() - INTERVAL \'7d\''),
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: There is a warning syntax error at or near \"\"7d\"\""

Comment: Could it be that you have double `"` both escaped?

Comment: Change  'NOW()    to "NOW() and end with " (double quote) then the \' can be just a '

Answer (score 19):

This solution is *without* the `moment.js` library.

#### Between 7 days ago and now

```
const sevenDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7));
models.instagram.findAll({
  where: {
    my_date: {
      $gt: sevenDaysAgo,
      $lt: new Date(),
    },
  },
});
```

#### Between now and 7 days from now

```
const sevenDaysFromNow = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7));
models.instagram.findAll({
  where: {
    my_date: {
      $gt: new Date(),
      $lt: sevenDaysFromNow,
    },
  },
});
```

Notes:

- `$gt` stands for "greater than". You could use `$gte` instead of `$gt`. `$gte` stands for "greater than or equal to". Same for `$lte` of course.
- Technically speaking, you need both `$lt` and `$gt` to make sure that the date isn't into the future (per the original question).
- Other answers show the use of `[Sequelize.Op.gt]` instead of `$gt`. Use that if on Sequelize v5.

Comment: thank you i was scrolling and scrollin hoping for a non moment.js solution :) this need more upvotes

Comment: Upvoted. There seems to be no compelling reason to use `moment`. https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html now gives a non-moment example:
`{ createdAt: { [Op.gt]: new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answers and comments, a way without using third party packages would be:

```
const sevenDaysFromNowResults = await db.ModelName.findAll({
      where: {
        createdAt: {
          [Sequelize.Op.gte]: new Date(new Date() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) // seven days ago
        }
      }
    })
```

The seven days are calculated using Date utility in milliseconds `(days * 24hrs * 60mins * 60secs * 1000ms)`