# Sequelize.js - Invalid date problem in where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize in a **MySQL** model with column as follows:

```js
      date: {
                    type: Sequelize.DATE,
                    field: 'utxn_date',
                    defaultValue: () => {
                        const now = new Date();
                        return `${formatISO(now, { representation: 'date' })} ${formatISO(now, {
                            representation: 'time',
                        })}`;
                    },
                },
```

At some moment, I need to filter this column, that I use the following code in my `where` (I tried to put a `Date()` component and also tried with a string as follows:

```js
where = {
    ...where,
    [sequelize.Op.lte]: {
        date: '2020-05-06 23:59', //endDateFilter,
    },
};
```

But, at every time, I got this error:

```
"Invalid value { utxn_date: '2020-05-06 23:59' }"
```

If I do a `SELECT` directly on my database, the result of the column will be as follow:

```
utxn_id | utxn_user_id |      utxn_date      | utxn_value
--------+--------------+---------------------+------------
 26     | 200          | 2019-10-26 10:15:52 | 100.00
```

Details about the table:

```
column      |  type
------------+------------
utxn_id     | bigint(20)
utxn_user_id| int(11)
utxn_date   | datetime
```

Everything seems to be fine. In other moments I used similar filters in `Sequelize.DATE` columns and worked well. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have You tried to pass `date: dateObject` or iso string: `date: dateObject.toISOString()` ?

Comment: Tried now, same error: `Invalid value { utxn_date: '2020-06-06T03:00:00.000Z' }`. Thanks for the try.

Comment: also try momentjs: `date: moment(dateObject).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')`

Comment: I use `date-fns` and tried to use `formatISO()` function. And the error is the same. The output created is the same as the `momentjs` will generate.

Comment: switch places of comparison operator with field name, see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798357/sequelize-where-statement-with-date

Comment: The places of comparison is the problem. Thanks