# how to check date that has no activity for past 10days in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

in the database I have a column called,
edited date. I need to write a query.

```
 where: {
           lastEditedDateTime:!moment().subtract(10, 'days').toDate()
}
```

I need to write query that finds the last edited date is greater than 10 days.

Comment: You need a `lt` operator for that: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize Where statement with date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798357/sequelize-where-statement-with-date)

Comment: @ChrisG no it doesnt

Comment: The accepted answer shows exactly how to do that, doesn't it? (also: "Does this answer your question?" is auto-inserted when you mark a question as dupe, I didn't type that myself, just fyi)

Comment: @chrisG im a begineer. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
where: {
  lastEditedDateTime: {
    [Op.lte]: moment().subtract(10, 'days').toISOString() 
  }
}
```

Here are the search operators in Sequelize: https://sequelizedocs.fullstackacademy.com/search-operators/.

Comment: The question is already marked as dupe, pointing to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061376/5734311)